# PayPal IPN to mysql database not working

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I'm trying to get my PayPal automatically inserts the payment in MySQL.

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS idevicev2 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  transactie_id varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  programma varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  naam varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  transactie_datum datetime NOT NULL,
  status varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  totaal_bedrag varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  ieverything_else text NOT NULL,
  username varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  active varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

And this is the script i use for IPN:

```
<?php
   //Change these with your information
$paypalmode = ''; //Sandbox for testing or empty ''
$dbusername     = 'myusername'; //db username
$dbpassword     = 'mypassword'; //db password
$dbhost     = 'localhost'; //db host
$dbname     = 'mydbname'; //db name

if($_POST)
{
        if($paypalmode=='sandbox')
        {
            $paypalmode     =   '.sandbox';
        }
    $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www'.$paypalmode.'.sandbox.paypal.com'));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
    {
        $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $username = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $itemname = $_POST['item_name'];
        $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $payeremail = $_POST['email'];
        $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
        $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
        $mcgross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST); 

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
        if (!$conn)
        {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

        // insert in our IPN record table
        $query = "INSERT INTO idevicev2
        (transactie_id,programma,naam,email,transactie_datum,status,totaal_bedrag,username,ieverything_else)
        VALUES
        ('$transaction_id','$itemname','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate','$paymentstatus','$mcgross','$username','$otherstuff')";

        if(!mysql_query($query))
        {
            //mysql error..!
        }
        mysql_close($conn);

    }
```

}
    ?>

Now when I go to: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator and enter my IPN URL, PayPal says IPN sent but i dont get the data in my MYSQL database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have "sandbox" in your Header. If `$paypalmode` is set, then you have 2 "sandbox"es in your Header...

Comment: @Digifaktur what do you mean with that

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www'.$paypalmode.'.sandbox.paypal.com'));` - remove "sandbox". This is probably not the solution to your problem, but it may help.

Comment: @Digifaktur Did'nt work

Comment: Based on what your IPN code is doing, it seems that either the IPN is not validating correctly with PayPal or you could have an error happening with MySQL that you're not seeing.  Take a look at this guide on [testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  It should help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AndrewAngell as first WOW what a nice site!! I just downloaded your PayPal IPN wordpress script and now i'm trying it to do with that one!

Comment: @AndrewAngell I really don't get it working, if I give you my login details, could you take a look at it?

Comment: @JeffreydeVos, what problem are you having with it?  It's really just a matter of updating the config file and installing it.  Nothing else would need to be done with it.  If you want to [submit an order for premium support](http://www.angelleye.com/product/premium-support/) I could help you more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with sandbox account. Now only have to change sandbox to ''

```
<?php
           //Change these with your information
        $paypalmode = 'sandbox'; //Sandbox for testing or empty ''
        $dbusername     = ''; //db username
        $dbpassword     = ''; //db password
        $dbhost     = ''; //db host
        $dbname     = ''; //db name

    if($_POST)
    {
            if($paypalmode=='sandbox')
            {
                $paypalmode     =   '.sandbox';
            }
            $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www'.$paypalmode.'.sandbox.paypal.com'));
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
            {
                $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
                $payerid = $_POST['payer_id'];
                $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
                $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
                $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
                $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
                $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
                $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
                $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);

                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
                if (!$conn)
                {
                 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

                // insert in our IPN record table
                $query = "INSERT INTO ibn_table
                (transactie_id,koper_id,naam,email,transactie_datum,betalings_status,ieverything_else)
                VALUES
                ('$transaction_id','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate', '$paymentstatus','$otherstuff')";

                if(!mysql_query($query))
                {
                    //mysql error..!
                }
                mysql_close($conn);

            }
    }
    ?>
```